# jquery toggle not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello people here is my JQUERY code below...

```
    $(function(){

    $(".block2").toggle(

    function(){$(this).text(1);},
    function(){$(this).text(0);});

    });
```

where `block2` is the same class name for 2 divs...what iam trying to do is if i click `first div` it should enter `1` in it.. If i click `second div(second time)` it should enter `0` how to fix this??

[demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/y5ra2/)

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: Which version of jQuery you are using? If I am not wrong `.toggle(function,function)` is removed from jQuery 1.9.

Comment: can you create a demo in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4heQW/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny demo link updated...

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KeG9n/1/ ?

Comment: @Arun P Johny yes exactly.... if u had put it in answer.. i would have accepted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    var counter = 0
    $(".block2").click(function () {
        $(this).text(counter++ % 2);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KeG9n/)

Comment: this will not work.... as you click on next block it is becoming 1 even if there is 1 if previous click value is 0.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('#first_div, #second_div').on('click',function(){
        $(".block2").text(function(){
            return $(this).text()==1 ? 0 : 1
        });
    });
});
```

**Updated** with same class `block2`

```
$(function(){
    $('.block2').on('click',function(){
        $(this).text(function(){
            return $(this).text()==0 ? 1 : 0;
        });
    });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/TpHt6/1/)

**[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/TpHt6/4/)** according to your `html code`

Comment: tjhanks for answering...but i know this way i want to use same class for both.. bcos i have more then ten divs i can not use different ids for all...

Comment: @Friend see this once http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/TpHt6/4/ , also remove the `id` as id must be unique

Answer (score -1):

This is the "click an element to run the specified functions" signature of .toggle(). It should not be confused with the "change the visibility of an element" of .toggle() which is not deprecated. The former is being removed to reduce confusion and improve the potential for modularity in the library. The jQuery Migrate plugin can be used to restore the functionality.
You can try this

```
$(function(){
$(".block2").click(function
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
        $(this).text(1);
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    } else {
        $(this).text(1);
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
    }
}); 
});
```